# Case Insensitive search in jquery-bootgrid

Tags: case-insensitive, jquery-bootgrid

Hi I have implemeted jquery-bootgrid. However, searching is based on case. My requirement is that searching should be done irrespective of case used i.e If am searching for "Australia" and the user types "australia" or "Australia" result should be same.

I looked into the documentation and the search setting only have "dealy" or "charatcers" option. So how should i implement case insensitive search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to switch the behaviour is named `caseSensitive` and documented under [General Settings](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation#table). I will move this option in the next major release to `searchSettings` for the sake of consistency.

Example:

```
$("#grid").bootgrid({
    caseSensitive: false
});
```